# Conditionals in the Model with C#

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I am working in Visual Studio with C# in an MVC architecture. Currently I am creating my conditional statements to render the data I need from the database I connected to the application. I have about 16 conditional statements. If I try to get data on a SalePerson alone it'll render, however if I use another filter on my query it'll break in 2 conditions. Can anyone give me advice on how I can re-organize my logic.
Here is my conditional statement:

```
if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode != ProductCode) && quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson)
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && ((quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode)) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode != ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode != ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    else if ((start != null && end != null) && (IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson)))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
```

Comment: This is a joke, right?

Comment: First off this question is better for stack code review.  1, extract `(start != null && end != null)` into its own if enxapsulating all of them.  Almost all of your logic has duplicates, remove all of them into their own if statements

Comment: Replace all your code with `myList.Add(quotes1);`

Comment: It's that bad @Smartis? Thanks @johnny 5 I'm doing that now.

Comment: You'll win an award for horror coding. Make a class that have the responsability of this rules to have only to ask this class if you can add or not the quote in the list.

Comment: LOL! Embarrassing. Well thanks for the advice all. I have a working -horrible looking- conditional statement that executes well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }

                    if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) &&  String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson)
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }

                    if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && ((quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode)) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson)))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson)))
                     {
                         myList.Add(quotes1);
                     }
                     if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPerson))
                     {
                         myList.Add(quotes1);
                     }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is much better :

```
           if ((start != null && end != null))
            {
                if (IncludeClosedQuotes == true && quotes1.QuoteStatus != null)
                {
                    if((ExcludeNoBid == false) && ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode)) || (quotes1.ProductCode != ProductCode)))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    if ((ExcludeNoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }

                    if ((ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    if((ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false) && (quotes1.ProductCode != ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                         myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                }

                if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == false))
                {
                    if (quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode)
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                    if ((quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                }
                if ((IncludeClosedQuotes == false) && (ExcludeNoBid == true && quotes1.NoBid == false))
                {
                    if ((quotes1.ProductCode == ProductCode) && (quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() != SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }

                    if((String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCode) && quotes1.SalesCode.ToString() == SalesPerson))
                    {
                        myList.Add(quotes1);
                    }
                }
          }
```